# Any advantage of assymetric matcher over a symmetric one?

Tags: jestjs, karma-jasmine

In jasmine/jest, what are benefits of creating an asymmetric custom matcher over a symmetric one?

Let's assume I have a code for a symmetric one which would be used as in:

```
expect(actual).toBeArrayOfLeapYears();
```

vs

```
expect(actual).toEqual(jasmine.arrayContainingLeapYears());
```

Code-wise, when I look at [ArrayContaining](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/main/src/core/asymmetric_equality/ArrayContaining.js), the asymmetric seem to induce less simple/clear code, but maybe I am missing some of their strong points.